# sql to pull values from array

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have values in array like below

```
Column X
[ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]
[ "A", "B"]
```

trying to get a result set like below,

```
Value  count
A  2
B  2
C  1
D  1
E  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `flatten` function :

```
select value , count(*)
from yourtable a
cross join table(flatten(a.ColumnX)) f
group by f.value
order by count(*)
```